# How to build ActiveMQ-CPP Stomp only client

Tags: stomp, activemq-cpp

Is it possible to build an ActiveMQ-CPP Client to support only STOMP Protocol? Regular native library with dependencies is too big for my embedded device and I want to build a client with just the STOMP support. Please advise.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not currently possible with the ActiveMQ-CPP client.  You could of course contribute to the project to make this possible.